# How to get the current data UID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo dropdown list inside kendo TreeViewGrid. I need to get the current data `UID`. There will be many dropdown lists with same class. I need to find out the current data `UID`.

```
 $('input.outputCategoryCode').kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select product...",
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "Value",
            dataValueField: "Key",
            dataSource: ProductData,
            change: function (e) {
                var value = this.value();
                if (value) {
                    //$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "OutPutCategoryCode", operator: "eq", value: parseInt(value) });

                    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

                    var dataUId = $("#Grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid]");

                    for (var i = 0; i <= dataUId.length; i++) {
                        var currentUID = $(dataUId[i]).attr('data-uid');
                        for (var j = 0; j <= grid.length; j++) {
                            if(grid[j].uid==currentUID) {                           
                            grid[j].OutPutCategoryCode = value;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } 
            }

           });
```

Comment: change `var currentUID = $(dataUId[i]).attr('data-uid');` to `var currentUID = $(dataUId[i]).data('uid');`

Comment: @guradio - Not able to get using "uid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
change: function (e) {
      var currentUID = $(this.element[0]).closest('.k-detail-row').prev().attr('data-uid')
```

Comment: Not able to get current row data-uid

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: In this above code having 4 grid (kendo tree grid). I binded dropdown in header. For each dropdown selection i have to add corresponding Value(outputcategorycode) to in kendo datasource. If any other approach also i'm welcoming from you..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to access `uid` inside the change event is:

```
this.dataItem().uid
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zt0p29gp/1/)